# How to output a value from ADF .NET Custom Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF that takes a Dataset input from Azure Data Lake Storage, it then has a pipeline with a custom .NET activity. The activity moves files from their Import folder into a custom folder location ready for processing and then deletes the original file.

I want to be able to pass the custom folder location back out into the activities pipeline so that I can give it to the next activity.

Is there a way of outputting the custom folder string to the activities pipeline?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

We have an improve item the output can be next customer activity's input. Its pending deployment. You can have a try **by the end of this month** :)

For how to use this feature:

Update code: Activity1:

```
Execute(...)    
 {   
   return new Dictionary<string, string> { "**Foo**", "Value" }
 }
```

Update pipeline: Activity2 Json:

```
"extendedProperties": { "ValueOfFoo", "**$$Foo**" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a "custom activity" as the title of the question suggest, this is possible using

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity#retrieve-execution-outputs

```
 @activity('MyCustomActivity').output.outputs[0]"
```

You can also consume the output in another activity as described here:

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity#pass-outputs-to-another-activity

> You can send custom values from your code in a Custom Activity back to the service. You can do so by writing them into outputs.json from your application. The service copies the content of outputs.json and appends it into the Activity Output as the value of the customOutput property. (The size limit is 2MB.) If you want to consume the content of outputs.json in downstream activities, you can get the value by using the expression

```
 @activity('<MyCustomActivity>').output.customOutput
```